# Excel 2007 - conditional formating - how to turn colour codes into colours?

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

I have a very simple macro code which shows the colour of the colour code which is recorded inside a cell:

```
Sub ShowColour()
    ColCod = Selection()
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = ColCod
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
End Sub
```

I am now looking for some way for changing the content of the cell into another colour code and be immediately shown it's colour. I have experimented with conditional formating, but it seems that I can only choose amongst pre-defined formats. Can anybody give me a hint?

Comment: Colours set by conditional formatting are not visible in Range.Interior.Color. Do you want the cell to change colour when the user inputs a colour code into it? You can use the OnChange event to run your subroutine.

Comment: Yes, I want the cell to change colour when the user inputs a _new_ colour code into it and that works already great. _In addition_ I want to see the colour of the originial colour code, so that the user can make up his mind which cells to modify, by inserting a new colour code.

Answer (score 1):

If I get you right you need to add this code into appropriate sheet module, like one named 'Sheet1 (Sheet1)' (not into standard module like Module1). As a result this code will fire appropriate event for you.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
With Target.Interior
    .Pattern = xlSolid
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = Target.Value
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
End With

Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox "Color number rather doesn't exists"
End Sub
```

I kept your basic code inside as it would be easier for you.

Comment: This works brilliantly. Thanks a lot! One more thing I haven't been able to work out yet: I'd like to see not only the colours in those fields I edited, but the original before editing as well and your code is only triggered when I make a change. Basically I am looking for a behaviour similar to that of conditional formatting. The cell shows a colour and when the content is changed, the colour changes.

Comment: 'I'd like to see not only the colours in those fields I edited, but the original before editing as well'... how?? In which way?? I don't get it... Did you try anything??

Comment: What I managed to do so far is to use your idea for writing a code that handles change in different colums and for different cell-content exactly as I hoped it would whenever I make a change in any cell. What I have not found yet is a way to show the colour codes in colour code columns to begin with, that is, before the user starts editing the cell-content. The file is created by a WinWord macro. I want a user to open it, look at the coloured cells in a colour codes containing column and decide: "In this particular cell, let me change the colour code into another one".